# method is not defined on backbone.js + coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have my javascript in **backbone.js** with **coffeescript** instead javascript:

```
TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend(
  toggleStatus ->
    if @.get 'status' is "incomplete"
      @.set 'status': 'complete' 
    else
      @.set 'status': 'incomplete'
    @.save()  
)

todoItem = new TodoItem(
  description: 'Play the guitar'
  status: 'incomplete'
  id: 1
)

TodoView = Backbone.View.extend(
  tagName: 'div'
  id: "box"
  className: 'red-box'

  template: 
    _.template "<h3> <input type=checkbox #{ print "checked" if status is "complete"} /> <%= description %></h3>"

  events: 
    "click h3": "alertStatus"
    'change input': 'toggleStatus'

  toggleStatus: ->
    @.model.toggleStatus()

  alertStatus: ->
    alert('Hey you clicked the h3!')

  render: ->
    @.$el.html @.template(@.model.toJSON())
)

todoView = new TodoView({model: todoItem})
todoView.render()
console.log todoView.el
```

Backbone version is the last version 0.9.10 and underscore.js version is last version 1.4.4

The coffeescript file compile fine however I get in console:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleStatus is not defined main.js:5**

**(anonymous function) main.js:5**

**(anonymous function)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you're trying to assign a anonymous function to your object at key `toggleStatus` at line 2.

Then, you just forget the `:` when declaring `toggleStatus`.